# Mysql query display group data

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL below

data

```
CREATE TABLE data
    (id int, name varchar(9), room varchar(9), paid varchar(9));

INSERT INTO data
    (id, name, room, paid)
VALUES
    (1, 'jane', 'room1','0'),
    (2, 'any', 'room2', '1'),
    (3, 'mandy', 'room2', '1'),
    (4, 'vivian', 'room2', '1'),
    (5, 'amber', 'room3', '1'),
    (6, 'fany', 'room4', '1'),
    (7, 'diana', 'room4', '0');
```

query

```
SELECT 
  data.room, COUNT(data.id) as total
FROM 
  data
WHERE 
  data.paid = 0
GROUP BY
  data.room
```

sample link [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df82e1/3)

result right now is

```
room 1 = 1 
room 4 = 1
```

result that I want

```
room 1 = 1
room 2 = 0
room 3 = 0
room 4 = 1
```

Comment: This is how to ask a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  data.room, SUM(data.paid = 0) as total
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY
  data.room;
```

See a [Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47620f/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  data.room, SUM(CASE WHEN data.paid = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY
  data.room
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df82e1/47)

Answer (score 1):

cdaiga's answer is correct, but relies on your values (having `0` and `1` allows you to do the `SUM` trick). In general, you want to left join your original table with the table resulting from your `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT original.room, IFNULL(pr.total, 0) AS total
FROM data original LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      data.room as paidrooms, COUNT(data.id) as total
    FROM 
      data
    WHERE
      data.paid = 0
    GROUP BY
      data.room
) as pr on original.room = pr.paidrooms
```

Link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df82e1/56)

Comment: Why increase the complexity with joins? As Edsger W. Dijkstra puts it, `Simplicity is prerequisite for reliability`.

Comment: @cdaiga Because I tend to avoid relying in conversion from boolean values to integers. Since MySQL itself says that `Nonzero values are considered true`, we cannot be always sure that at some point your `data.paid = 0` won't become something not consistent with our problem. @Grace's answer, in that sense, is "safer" :)

Comment: I don't think I can, in the sense that my point depends on how boolean values are translated in integer. As long as the value is `1` everything is fine, and it should be like that, I'm not complaining. If, God knows why, MySQL developers change it to `2`, your solution stops working, as it will sum sets of 2s instead of 1s.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand, you want to list all rooms with a total amount of unpaid bills for each of them.
You cold use a nested select like follows:

```
    SELECT 
    d1.room, 
    (SELECT COUNT(d2.room) FROM data d2 WHERE d1.room = d2.room and d2.paid = 0)   as total
    FROM 
        data d1
    GROUP BY
        d1.room
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47620f/4)